# Is it possible to know the current files that Task Parallel.ForEach handle?

Tags: c#, .net, task

Please see this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> _source;
public void doWork()
{
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_source,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                //finish...
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

this method received `IEnumerable<string>` list and handle my files simultaneously and i want to find a way to know the current files that handle, i know i can use `file` variable and fired up event but i case my list contain several duplicate files it will be a problem so my question is if there is a way to know the current list indexes that in process ?

Comment: Why not filter your list from duplicates before doing Parallel.Foreach

Comment: Because sometimes i need this duplicated files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You said you can know the current String but you might have problem with duplicates**, then :

convert `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<Tuple<int,string>>` to differentiate between duplicates.

```
private IEnumerable<Tuple<int,string>> WithIndecies(IEnumerable<string> _source)
{
      int i =1;
      return _source.Select(x => Tuple.Create(i++, x));
}
```

**usage :**

```
List<string> abc = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b" };
var res = WithIndecies(abc);
```

result :

(1,a)

(2,a)

(3,b)

**Edit for your Code:**

```
CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
        private IEnumerable<string> _source;
        int _parallelThreads = 10;
        private Tuple<int,String> Currenct_Item;

        public void doWork()
        {
            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _tokenSource.Token;

            IEnumerable<Tuple<int,string>> _indexed_source = WithIndecies(_source);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(_indexed_source,
                        new ParallelOptions
                        {
                            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                        },
                        file =>
                        {
                            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                return;
                            Currenct_Item = file; // Save CurrentFile and Access it from anywhere else to see current file being processed

                            // file.Item2 is the String so use it in the 'do work'
                            //do work...
                        });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

            }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        //finish...
                    }
                , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
                );
        }

        private IEnumerable<Tuple<int,string>> WithIndecies(IEnumerable<string> _source)
        {
            int i =1;
            return _source.Select(x => Tuple.Create(i++, x));
        }
```

Comment: Can you show me please how to use it inside my method ?

Comment: Select has an overload that eliminates the i++ requirement.  `_source.Select((x,i) => Tuple.Create(i,x))`

Comment: I Know. I was just trying to make it simpler. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand how to use it, i have this new list but i cannot use this list instead of _source

Comment: Editing the answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know the index, there is an overload which sents a int64 representing the index:

```
ForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>,   ParallelOptions, Action<TSource, ParallelLoopState, Int64>)
```

From MSDN:

Executes a foreach (For Each in Visual Basic) operation with 64-bit indexes on an IEnumerable in which iterations may run in parallel, loop options can be configured, and the state of the loop can be monitored and manipulated